# How can I create a new column after 8 items for the data pulled from database in MVC using forloop?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Currently this is my code to pull a list of items from database an show under a Menu item:

```
<div class="top">
<ul>
<li class='itemCaption f17o'>&nbsp;</li>
@foreach (var category in Model.CatList)
{
<li>
<a href="/c/@category.Id/@category.Name" class='white'>@category.Name</a>
</li>
}
</ul>
</div>
```

I tried the same using the code below also, but even though the logic seems right the variable named value creates problems... since i am very new to MVC its also a headache for me...

```
@foreach (var category in Model.CatList.Select((Value, i => new { i, Value }))
{
    if (category.i % 8 == 0)
    {
        @("</ul></li><li><ul>")
    }
    <li>
        <a href="/c/@category.Value.Id/@category.Value.Name" class='white'>@category.Value.Name</a>
    </li>
}
```

.. Can someone plese help me to rewrite the code in For-loop instead of for-each..

Comment: I think you should post more info about what you are trying to accomplish. For instance what's the purpose of the 8 divider?

Comment: its for a dropdown menu..i need to pull the data from the database and show this in my menu item when i click it..i.e. when i click it it must show all the data in the database ..basically names..

Comment: currently even though i am able to pull it from the database.. it is shown as a single list in a single column ..all listed downwards.. i want it to be just 8 items in a column  and after the 8th item a new column should start at the side and it must also continue till it has 8 items ..and again after the 8th it must split...and hence go on

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use your mode but I hope you can adapt the example below

```
@foreach (var x in Enumerable.Range(0, 200))
{
    if (x % 8 == 0)
    {
        @:<ul>
        @:<li>@x</li>
    }
    else if (x % 8 == 7)
    {
        @:<li>@x</li>
        @:</ul>
    }
    else {
         @:<li>@x</li>
    }
}
```

If this isn't what you were trying to accomplish let me know and I will edit

EDIT

With your model should be

```
@foreach (var category in Model.CatList.Select((Value, i) => new { i, Value }))
{
    if (category.i % 8 == 0)
    {
        @:<ul>
        @:<li><a href="/c/@Value.Id/@Value.Name" class='white'>@Value.Name</a></li>
    }
    else if (category.i % 8 == 7)
    {
        @:<li><a href="/c/@Value.Id/@Value.Name" class='white'>@Value.Name</a></li>
        @:</ul>
    }
    else {
         @:<li><a href="/c/@Value.Id/@Value.Name" class='white'>@Value.Name</a></li>
    }
}
```

Comment: a doubt here...in the first code i posted .. you can see that i have pulled the data from database and loaded it into a variable named Category...how is that loaded n the code you game me?

Comment: i mean the code area here:                                         var category in Model.CatList

Comment: and wht does this do?:                                              var x in Enumerable.Range(0, 200)

Comment: Enumerable.Range(0, 200) generates an array of int(s) from 0 to 200. I updated my answer

Comment: no it still doesnt work ..if there was an option to fix an attachment i could have shown u a pic of the display..its still the same except tht the current column has a small break and the last 2 items are shown leaving a ittle more gap from the ones on top

Comment: But what is the use of the variable 'Value' in the above code?

Comment: ok, I see your problem. I took the code from your example. I re-edited

Comment: it's hard to debug through stackoverflow :(. you can use http://imgur.com to share print screens of http://jsfiddle.net/ for code

Comment: hmm okie..bad luck...so what could be the reason for this?its really not splitting at all

Comment: The whole code is too long..But i have marked the area i need help  here as a comment...<ul class='fl'>
 <li class='itemCaption f17o'>Shop By</li>
<li><a href='#' class='white'>All Brands</a></li>            <li>       <a href="../Bestseller/Index" class='white'>Best Sellers</a></li>
 </ul>
 <div class="clear"></div>
  </ul><ul class="fr"><div class="top">
 <ul><li class='itemCaption f17o'>&nbsp;</li>
@*  Help required here*@
 @foreach (var category in Model.CatList)
 { <li><a href="/c/@category.Id/@category.Name"class='white'>@category.Name</a></li>
 }@*help required till above*@ </ul></div>

Comment: this itself was reduced to exactly 100 characters..sorry

Comment: ok i got it no...first add a count to its model class like this :                                                             public int MenuCount

        {
            get
            {

                return 5;
            }
        
        }

Comment: now add this code in the cshtml page like this:                                                         <li><a href="/c/@Model.CatList[0].Id/@Model.CatList[0].Name" class='white'>@Model.CatList[0].Name"------0"</a></li>
@for (int i = 1; i < Model.CatList.Count(); i++)
{<li><a href="/c/@Model.CatList[i].Id/@Model.CatList[i].Name" class='white'>@Model.CatList[i].Name"------"@i</a></li>
 if (i % Model.MenuCount == 0  )
                           {
                              
                               @Html.Raw("</ul><ul>");

                           }

                       }

Comment: if you want the info to be displayed as columns than you shouldn't use ul, you should use tables

Comment: the above code works ..i was using a fluidic design without use of any tables all along..the above code really works without the tables @alexb